# MX130 stuck on 400Mhz

Tags: gpu, integrated-graphics

i have a Yoga 530 laptop with i5-8250u and MX-130 running on Windows 10. However efficiency of mine MX130 is far below expectations. MSI afterburner says it's stuck on fixed 400 Mhz.

[image: screenshot of Afterburner]

When I turn on games, this doesn't change. FPS are very low while MX130 is 100% load with 60ºC. CPU and Memory Clocks are floating around 400 Mhz.

Any solutions?
Drivers from Nvidia are updated.

Comment: Did you check your Power Plan settings? Are you on the battery or plugged in?

Comment: Is there a change whenever the power adapter is disconnected/reconnected?

Comment: Plugged in, power plan set to max, no difference whenever power plug is connected, disconnected